# What is DavWWWRoot?

Tags: .net, webdav

I am connecting to my *WebDAV* server in Windows Explorer as `\\myserver@8080\DavWWWRoot\`. I can not find any folder called `DavWWWRoot` on my server in my storage or in the *WebDAV* server back-end code. Where does this `DavWWWRoot` come from?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Taken from http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/access/windows

"`DavWWWRoot` is a special keyword recognized by Windows Shell. There is no such folder exists on your WebDAV server and you should not create it. You also will not find any `DavWWWRoot` name in requests to your server. The `DavWWWRoot` keyword tells Mini-Redirector driver, that handles WebDAV requests, that you are connecting to the root of WebDAV server.

You can avoid using this keyword if you specify folder that exists on your server when connecting to server. For example: `\\webdavserver.com\sales\`

in this case `DavWWWRoot` will not appear in urls."

Answer (score 9):

According to "[Understanding and Troubleshooting SharePoint Explorer View](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=9981)": "DavWWWRoot is a special keyword that alerts the WebDAV client that you are referring to the root of a WebDAV server". It is used by the Mini-redirector instead of the folder name, to indicate server root.

If your WebDAV location is at `http://host:8080/cms/dav/`, Windows Shell (mini-redirector) can connect to `\\host@8080\DavWWWRoot\cms\dav\` or to `\\host@8080\cms\dav\`. There is no folder named 'DavWWWRoot' in your storage, there are only 'cms' and 'dav' folders. You do not need to create folder with DavWWWRoot name on your server, this is purely ‘client’ Mini-redirector hack.