# How to save workbook opened as read-only

Tags: excel, vba, save

I have trouble saving WB that is opened as a read-only (from SharePoint server). Tried to add `ReadOnly:=False` to line that opens up the workbook, but vba still stopps and points to line `wb_gr.Save`.
Is there a way to get around this?
My code is located in a "master-dash" (same folder), that updates itself first, then opens next Dash, updates, saves and closes. And so on...
When opening "master-dash", I click and remove all warnings = it updates and saves ok.

```
Sub UpdateDash()

Dim fPath As String
Dim wb_gr As Workbook

        fPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
        If Right(fPath, 1) = "\" Then
        fPath = Left(fPath, Len(fPath) - 1)
        End If

Set wb_gr = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\dashboard.xlsm", ReadOnly:=False, Notify:=False)  

'(lot of updating going on - works just fine)

wb_gr.Save           '(Run-time error 1004. No access to file C:\windows\system32\CC90FF60)
wb_gr.Close False
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you really put your workbook in `C:\windows\system32`? why?

Comment: No, I have not. All files is located in SharePoint, like this: `https://myjob.sharepoint.com/sites/FAG/PlanAndUpdates/2021/Dash/`  I have no idea why error code is refering as it does.

Comment: Why not save.as then copy it to the original location.

Comment: What is the *actual value* of  `ThisWorkbook.Path` (you should obscure the actual domain/folder/file names, but don't "simplify" the components)  ?

Comment: Basic question:  Do you have write privileges on these files the normal way of editing Excel?  I know our SharePoint sites have access rights where I have superpowers on some sites, and read-only access on others.  Also, for the files I modify with VBA, I have to use an odd format of URL, like `\\mycompany.shpt.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites\mShare\Shared Documents\myFile.xlsx`.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706142/what-is-davwwwroot)

Comment: Relevant "basic question".. :-) I just sent a request til the IT-people at my job.